# How can a Spring Boot Application using Hibernate interact with multiple tables, all structured identically?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a MySQL database called "currency", with over a hundred tables, each one for one currency, and all in identical structure (2 columns, a datetime for a timestamp and a float for a rate).

How can a Spring Boot Application interact with this structure?

I would like to just have one class CurrencyRate with the fields and getter/setter methods. If I mark this class `@Entity`, `@Table`, then I can access only one table. I have investigated the `@SecondaryTable` mark, but it seems to be only for situations in which we would want to interact with multiple tables at once, rather than just one.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.DateSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.NumberSerializers.FloatSerializer;

public abstract class CurrencyRate implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @JsonSerialize(using=DateSerializer.class)
    private Date datetime;

    @NotBlank
    @JsonSerialize(using=FloatSerializer.class)
    private float rate;

    Date getDate () { return this.datetime; }
    void setDate (Date timestamp) { this.datetime = timestamp; }
    float getRate () { return this.rate; }
    void setRate (float rate) { this.rate = rate; } 
}
```

I had the idea that I could make CurrencyRate an abstract class (as in the image provided), and then create a class for each currency that inherits from this class. This would be very tedious, but at least it might work. However, it seems that not only would I have to create a class for each currency model, but a class for each repository as well.

Unless there is a way to serve this structure without doing all that? Any ideas? Currently looking over the documentation and searching for others with this problem, but it doesn't seem like this structure is very common.

**Edit:**

I want to add the controller because I believe it is the location at which the logical problem of differentiating between children of the abstract class occurs.

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rates")
class CurrencyRateController {

    @Autowired
    private CurrencyRateService service;

    @GetMapping("/allEUR")
    public List<CurrencyRate> getAllEUR() {
        return service.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/allCAD")
    public List<CurrencyRate> getAllCAD() {
        return service.findAll();
    }
}
```

The above controller returns the CAD values for both /allCAD and /allEUR, I assume because the CurrencyRateService uses a CurrencyRateRepository. Somewhere, Hibernate tries to differentiate between the EUR subclass and the CAD subclass, but they are identical. Therefore CAD values are given for all requests.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to use the proper inheritance strategy. Like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class CurrencyRate {
  (... omitted for brevity ...)
}
```

Subclasses:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USDOLLAR")
public class UnitedStatesDollar extends CurrencyRate {
}

@Entity
@Table(name="EURO")
public class Euro extends CurrencyRate {
}
```

And the same for other currencies. You should be able to query against `CurrencyRate` class, retrieving all results from all tables and you will have to use `instanceof` to distinguish currencies. Also you will able to perform a query against a single currency.

If you want to see more about inheritance take a look [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm trying to implement your proposed solution. However, I don't see the connection between the REST API and a call to a specific currency table. For example, we go to mysite/resources/findAllEURO. We expect to get all data in the EURO table. We have a CurrencyRateService, who uses a CurrencyRate repository, which extends JpaRepository<CurrencyRate, Integer>. How can that repository know to query the EURO table? Thanks for your help. Edit: It seems to be working with just one child class of the abstract class CurrencyRate. I will inviestigate further.

Comment: To query single currency you should create a specific repository for that currency.

Comment: There's no way to have one repository handle more than one table? We're looking at one repository per currency, and there are a lot of currencies.

Comment: Yes, the CurrencyRateRepository that you have should be perfectly fine to handle all your currencies.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario,I think Single Table strategy should be used as it will create one table for each class hierarchy. This is also the default strategy chosen by JPA if we don’t specify one explicitly.
You can define the strategy you want to use by adding the @Inheritance annotation to the super-class:
Parent Entity:-

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class CurrencyRate  {
    @Id
    @JsonSerialize(using=DateSerializer.class)
    private Date datetime;

    @NotBlank
    @JsonSerialize(using=FloatSerializer.class)
    private float rate;

    // constructor, getters, setters
}
```

SubClasses with no field:-

```
@Entity
public class Rupee extends CurrencyRate {

}

@Entity
public class Dollar extends CurrencyRate {

}
```

Since the records for all entities will be in the same table, Hibernate provides a way to differentiate between these table rows.
A discriminator column is added in this case called DTYPE which has the name of the entity as a value.

You could create repository for CurrencyRate and then query the CurrencyRate table based on DType column.

Comment: This idea seems like it has promise, but as it stands I receive an SQLSyntaxErrorException with the message: Table 'currency_rate' doesn't exist. How can I avoid querying the superclass?